# remove gravity from addBody object

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

Hi my 'helicopter object' need to have a body to interact with enemy objects.
So i got:

```
helicopterspriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("helicopters.png", 113, 55)
helicoptersprites = sprite.newSpriteSet(helicopterspriteSheet, 1, 4)
sprite.add(helicoptersprites, "helicopters", 1, 4, 1000, 0)
helicopter = sprite.newSprite(helicoptersprites)
helicopter.x = -80
helicopter.y = 350
helicopter:prepare("helicopters")
helicopter:play()
helicopter.collided = false
helicopter:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint);
physics.addBody(helicopter, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=10})
screenGroup:insert(helicopter)
```

But how can i stop gravity interfering with the helicopter, as it is controlled by the 'Accelerometer' but the gravity keep pulling it down.

maybe i can fix it by  `self:applyForce(0, -1.5, self.x, self.y)`  on tilt but how to do this ?

Comment: Fixed by adding `helicopter.gravityScale = 0`

Comment: Glad to hear you worked it out :) But, you should post an answer to your question and approve it so your question wont show up in "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding helicopter.gravityScale = 0